# What is required to get car insurance in Australia?

Tags: australia, car-insurance

I'll be arriving in Australia (Melbourne) on 18 March 2015. I'll need to buy a car very soon after I arrive and I'll need to get car insurance. I have a full Irish driving license and 7 year's experience. What else do I need to get insurance?

Answer (score 4):

There are two flavours of car insurance in Victoria:

1. **Compulsory Third Party** (CTP) insurance is mandatory and included with your car registration ("rego").  Prices are fixed, around $750/year all in at time of writing, and everything is handled by [VicRoads](https://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/registration), the state road agency.  If you purchase a used car, it may include some months of prepaid rego and this may affect the purchase price; you'll still have to pay to get the rego transferred to you.
2. "**Car insurance**" means anything beyond this: third party property (damage to other people's cars), third party fire & theft, and comprehensive (covers your own car as well).  This is optional but recommended, although people driving old clunkers often don't bother.  Try [Compare the Market](http://www.comparethemarket.com.au/car-insurance/australia/victoria/) to see prices.  Note that, as a rule, only experience driving in Australia counts, so you'll be paying full premiums to start off with.